# Python : how do i import variable from one higher directory?

Tags: python, importerror

How do I import from a higher level directory in python?

For example, I have:

```
/var/www/PROJECT/subproject/_common.py 
/var/www/PROJECT/subproject/stuff/routes.py
```

I want to import variable `A` in `_common.py` to `routes.py`

```
# routes.py

import os, sys   
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
from _common import A
```

but I get the error:

```
ImportError:cannot import name 'A'
```

Comment: Have you check this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: Did you include `project/__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Cartucho yes i have project/__init__.py file

Comment: @AvichalBettoli most of them i tried. i also tried from .._common import A but it gives import beyond top-level package error

Comment: Maybe replacing `".."` by `"../.."`?

Comment: @임지웅 I have edited the answer. Please check the addition.

Answer (score 0):

**OLD VERSION**

To solve the issue replace `".."` with `os.pardir`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)))
from _common import A
```

**NEW VERSION**

The code above does not solve the problem in the question because the true problem lies in the project structure not in the particular line. The problem is *circular import*. The problem became clear after the full traceback has been provided. Here is the simple way to reproduce the issue - consider 3 files...

main.py:

```
import a
```

a.py:

```
import b
A = 'A'
```

b.py:

```
from a import A
```

... the error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'A'
```

OR

b.py:

```
import a
BB = a.A
```

... the error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'A'
```

The solution to the problem has been discussed many times - [search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20circular%20import)

Comment: same here, i tried, still import error saying cannot import name 'A'

Comment: @임지웅 Does your `_common.py` script really contain `A`? Maybe `A` is located inside some function or conditional structure? Can you provide the code of `_common.py`?

Comment: from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, Blueprint
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from __init__ import app
from db_controller.function import get_db

import os, sys

A = get_db('mysql')

Comment: @임지웅 I tested the code with `_common.py` containing a single line `A = "this is A"`. And the code works. Try this very simple version. Also, please edit your question - add `_common.py` content and full traceback for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change file directory:

```
import os, sys   
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"../../project")))
from _common import A
```

Comment: i tried, still import error saying cannot import name 'A'

Comment: You have to go from routes.py to two top file paths. You enter PROJECT after the two files are up. And enter the subproject directory and you can import import _common.py. Path = "../../subproject". If still not working, make sure it has A function in _common. @임지웅

Comment: As I understand it, A is not a function. A is a variable. You can't import a variable. Your create a functioan and return A variable. After import and use A variable. @임지웅